# UNITY3D c# Teleport object on certain amount of points

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I encountered a problem with this code. The "Killer" teleports to the location and immediately goes back to the starting position. I have 7 locations for the "Killer" to teleport to (around the player).  Whats wrong with this code? (I am a newbie) If possible could you add a sound to every point collected? example. When I get 1 points a sound/audio file plays. Thanks for answers!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class FpsScoreScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public int points;
bool isTeleported1 = false;
bool isTeleported2 = false;
bool isTeleported3 = false;
bool isTeleported4 = false;
bool isTeleported5 = false;
bool isTeleported6 = false;
bool isTeleported7 = false;
bool isTeleported8 = false;
public GameObject Killer;
public GameObject Player;
public Transform Destination;
public Transform KillerDestFarBack;
public Transform KillerDestCloseBack;
public Transform KillerDestRight;
public Transform KillerDestLeft;
public Transform KillerDestRightFront;
public Transform KillerDestLeftFront;
public Transform KillerDestFront;

public void Update()
{
    if (points == 1 && !isTeleported1)
    {
        Teleport1();
    }
    if (points == 2 && !isTeleported2)
    {
        Teleport2();
    }
    if (points == 3 && !isTeleported3)
    {
        Teleport3();
    }
    if (points == 4 && !isTeleported4)
    {
        Teleport4();
    }
    if (points == 5 && !isTeleported5)
    {
        Teleport5();
    }
    if (points == 6 && !isTeleported6)
    {
        Teleport6();
    }
    if (points == 7 && !isTeleported7)
    {
        Teleport7();
    }
    if (points == 8 && !isTeleported8)
    {
        Teleport8();
    }
}
void Teleport1()
{
    isTeleported1 = true;
    Killer.transform.position = KillerDestFront.transform.position;
}
void Teleport2()
{
    isTeleported2 = true;
    Killer.transform.position = KillerDestRightFront.transform.position;
}
void Teleport3()
{
    isTeleported3 = true;
    Killer.transform.position = KillerDestLeftFront.transform.position;
}
void Teleport4()
{
    isTeleported4 = true;
    Killer.transform.position = KillerDestRight.transform.position;
}
void Teleport5()
{
    isTeleported5 = true;
    Killer.transform.position = KillerDestLeft.transform.position;
}
void Teleport6()
{
    isTeleported6 = true;
    Killer.transform.position = KillerDestFarBack.transform.position;
}
void Teleport7()
{
    isTeleported7 = true;
    Killer.transform.position = KillerDestCloseBack.transform.position;
}
void Teleport8()
{
    isTeleported8 = true;
    Player.transform.position = Destination.transform.position;
}
```

}

Comment: To play sound, you will need to add an AudioSource Component

Comment: Ok. How do I specify a certain audio source to play when I have for example 2 points?

Comment: Did you try using if-else if statements?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using many Transform vars, I would prefer using a transform array, also I have used an array of bools has teleported. I would prefer you to follow some tutorials or get a book. Add a collider to your player and the coin.

```
[SerializeField] Transform[] teleportPoints;
[SerializeField]Transform coin;
bool[] hasTeleported;
AudioSource source;
int points = 0 ;

void Awake()
{
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    hasTeleported = new bool[teleportPoints.Length];
}


private void Update()
{

    for(int i = 0; i <= teleportPoints.Length; i++)
    {
        if (points == i && !hasTeleported[i])
        {
            Teleport(i);
        }

    }         
}

void Teleport(int index)
{
    transform.position = teleportPoints[index].position;
    hasTeleported[index] = true;
}


void IncreasePoints()
{
    source.Play();
    points++;
}

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if(collision.gameObject == coin.gameObject)
    {
        IncreasePoints();
    }
}
```